# How to LOOP a SELECT query until it finds a data on database (PHP to MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to select a row in the database, but if row is not in the database, it should loop until it finds the

This line
`$prev_date = date('M d, Y', strtotime($macrodate .' -1 day'));` transforms the currentdate to one down (lets say Jun 15, it will transform to Jun 14). And use that date to check if the date is in the database, it not, it will loop and go to Jun 13. Until it could find the date.

How do I do this? What loop should I use?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users_macros WHERE userid = '$userid' AND `date` = '$macrodate'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

                while(1) {
                    $prev_date = date('M d, Y', strtotime($macrodate .' -1 day'));
                    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users_macros WHERE userid = '$userid' AND `date` = '$prev_date'";
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) != 0) { 
                        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                        $targetcarbs = $row2['carbs']; 
                        $targetproteins = $row2['proteins']; 
                        $targetfats = $row2['fats']; 
                        $con->query("INSERT INTO users_macros VALUES('','$userid','$targetproteins','$targetfats','$targetcarbs','$macrodate')");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                
                
            }
```

Comment: what does it means  `while(1)` ?

Comment: @KUMAR It's the same as `while(true)`

Comment: You do not need to loop. Just write a sql statement that finds the most recent date in the table for that user ID,

Comment: @Barmar sir it is same as `while (expression) { statement(s) }` ?

Comment: Yes, and the expression is `1`, which is always truthy. So it loops until the `break` statement is executed.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Im not looking for recent date, im looking for the previous dates of their selected date if the date isnt in the database

Comment: Then you search for the most recent date before your selected date. That would include the day before of course.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a loop. Just use a query that returns the row with the highest date lower than `$macrodate`. And you can combine that with the `INSERT` query.

And add a `NOT EXISTS` criteria to make it select nothing if the given date is already in the table.

Also, use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "
    INSERT INTO users_macros
    SELECT '', userid, proteins, fats, carbs, ? FROM users_macros
    FROM users_macros
    WHERE userid = ? AND date < ?
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM users_macros
        WHERE userid = ? AND date = ?
    )
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 1");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $macrodate, $userid, $macrodate, $userid, $macrodate);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Not looking for the highest date sir. Im looking for the previous dates of the selected date of the user if the selected date isnt in the database.

Comment: Isn't the previous date the same as the highest date that's lower than `$macrodate`?